# Is there any mock library in .NET which can mock system time?

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Is there any mock library in .NET which can mock system time, whichever mock library is OK to me, like moq etc.?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I disagree that this question is off-topic. The OP is asking for a very specific feature. If it had been worded differently, e.g. "how can I mock system time in .NET", nobody would think of voting to close it as off-topic. Maybe this question breaks the "no tool recommendation" rule in letter, but not in spirit.

Comment: @Adam Lee, I suggest you reword your question as Thomas Levesque mentioned to get around the pedant filter.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque if this is reworded as you suggested it will become a commonly asked dupe.

Answer (score 5):

There are tools like [TypeMock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) or [Microsoft Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) that can mock things like `DateTime.Now`, but they're not free (for TypeMock Isolator you need at least the "Essential" edition, and for MS Fakes you need Visual Studio Enterprise).

However, you don't really need that. Rather than mocking `DateTime.Now`, you can create an abstraction over it, and that abstraction can be mocked. Something like this:

```
public interface ITimeService
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

Instead of using `DateTime.Now` directly in your code, inject an instance of `ITimeService`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ITimeService _timeService;

    public MyClass(ITimeService timeService)
    {
         _timeService = timeService;
    }

    public int GetCurrentYear()
    {
        return _timeService.Now.Year;
    }
}
```

The "real" implementation of `ITimeService` would just return `DateTime.Now`. And in your unit tests, you can use any mocking framework (FakeItEasy, Moq, NSubstitute...) to make a mock time service that you control. For instance, using FakeItEasy:

```
// Arrange
var timeService = A.Fake<ITimeService>();
A.CallTo(() => timeService.Now).Returns(new DateTime(1969, 7, 21));
var myClass = new MyClass(timeService);

// Act
var year = myClass.GetCurrentYear();

// Assert
year.Should().Be(1969);
```

Comment: That's requires a lot of change in source code since i need to add interface?

Comment: @AdamLee it's not that big a change if you already use dependency injection. Anyway, mocking `DateTime.Now` will require code changes, short of buying the expensive tools I mentioned. Another possible approach is to use a static read-write `TimeService.Now` property. It means less changes to your code, but it's not very clean, as it introduces global state; it won't allow you to run tests in parallel.